# How to Search a specfic value in parse.com?

Tags: android, parse-platform

Method checkMobileTableAccount uses to check a phone number in table Account, strMobile is phone number to search.

```
public boolean checkMobileTableAccount(final String strMobile) {
    result = false;
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Account");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
            for (ParseObject user : objects) {
                String mobile = user.getString("phonenumber");
                if (strMobile.equals(mobile)) {
                    result = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    });
    return result;
}
```

How can I get result after for loop finished?

Comment: make cloud function and use `promises`

Comment: for (ParseObject user : objects) {
                        String mobile = user.getString("phonenumber");
                        if (strMobile.equals(mobile)) {
                        //You can do the function here itself.The controls comes to here only if the phonenumber is equal.
                            break;
                        }
                    }

Comment: Can't you add a filter to the query? You don't need to loop over all the user objects.

Comment: read more in docs about 'queries' and just get that phone number you want  query.whereEqualTo("phonenumber", {strmobile});

Answer (score 0):

Just dont use method findInBackground(). Use find() which is not making your request in background.

```
public boolean checkMobileTableAccount(final String strMobile) {
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Account");
        try {
            List<ParseObject> objects = query.find();
            for (ParseObject user : objects) {
                String mobile = user.getString("phonenumber");
                if (strMobile.equals(mobile)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }
```